# Firefox disable extension on local files

Tags: firefox, html, firefox-extensions, browser-addons, localhost

Is it possible to disable selected firefox extensions from acting upon local files starting with `file://` as this might be security issue?

Any suggestions?

Google Chrome has this feature, unfortunately I am unable to do this for firefox.

*Is it possible to enable and disable this feature for individual extensions?*

Answer (score 3):

The local files have no domain. You can verify it by opening the console with <kbd>F12</kbd> when displaying a local file and executing this command : `console.log(document.domain)`.
So we can restrict extension when there is no domain :)

Open a new tab and type `about:config` in the address bar.
Accept to take risk when Firefox warns you.
In the new window, search for an option called `extensions.webextensions.restrictedDomains`. You will see that there are already several domains listed here, mainly around Mozilla websites. Edit the value and in the end, append a simple comma :
[image: restrictedDomains option ending with a comma]

From now on, Firefox will restrict extensions for pages that have no domain, including local files.

Comment: Is it possible to enable and disable this feature for individual extensions?

Comment: If there is a way to do it, I don't know it. It's less straightforward, but you could simply have two Firefox profiles, one with the restriction on no-domain, one without, and install your extensions for only one of the profiles...